# ASP.net WebAPI ignoring web.config?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, web-config, .net-core-rc2

I am setting up a web.config in wwwroot to redirect all requests to `index.html` for angularjs to handle.  This excludes existing files and folders and anything from `/api`.

The problem is, it's not working that way. I simply get blank pages for anything where a file does not exist.

Here is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="IndexHomeRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can't figure out any reason for it to still be trying to load the files instead of redirecting them to `index.html`

I am using .NET Core RC2 and I have static files and default files set to be used. I am using VS2015.  I set the project up as a WebAPI from the beginning. Not empty.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core does not use web.config](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#getting-and-setting-configuration-settings). Are you trying to port your existing ASP.NET application to ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I'm building a new application using WebAPI and trying to make it so all links redirect to index.html unless there is an existing file or they are under api/... however that does not appear to be happening.  Instead blank pages are being shown and a 404 in the Network tab of Chrome dev tools is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:

```
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Api",
        template: "api/{controller}/{action?}/{*path}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home" });

    options.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 });
```

Comment: That did not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I think it's because I am not using views but rather I want everything to redirect to wwwroot/index.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot one more part: inside the code for the Home/Index action, you redirect to the index.html file.